# Error handling iframe with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, http-error

I'm using `$("#element").attr("src", "http://url.com/page");` to set several iframes.

Is there a way to determine if an HTTP error occurred while setting a specific iframe and handle it accordingly?

Comment: Cross domain iframe or not?

Comment: yes. Cross domain iframe.

Comment: AFAIK, cross domain iframe doesn't fire any onerror js event (maybe this behaviour is browser dependant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onerror` event of the `<iframe>` does not work anymore, unfortunately.

Still, you could use a workaround like this :

- Bind a `load` event to all of the iframes you are loading
- Throw a `setTimeout` with arbitrary time for each `<iframe>`, like 60000 (1mn) or less in the mean time

If the load event triggers, clear the `setTimeout`.

It's not complete error handling, more a workaround. I used to do it with `JSONP` requests as there is no error handling too.

```
var timeout;
$("#iframe").attr("src", "url-cross-domain.html").on("load", function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    console.log("loaded !");
}):
timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    $("#iframe").off("load").remove();
    console.error("iframe loading failed");
}, 60000);
```

It has several limitations, for example you'll be unable to get the request response code. But it worth a try.